# fail to remove broken install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm struggling to remove libssl3 with apt `--fix-broken install`. I've also tried `sudo apt install -f` but it returns the same error.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  elinks-data filezilla-common gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1
  javascript-common libev4 libevent-2.1-7 libexpat1-dev libfilezilla-common
  libfilezilla24 libfsplib0 libhiredis0.14 libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjs-underscore liblua5.1-0 libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2
  libmessaging-menu0 libminiupnpc17 libnatpmp1 libpugixml1v5 libpython3-dev
  libpython3.10-dev libtokyocabinet9 libtre5 libwxbase3.0-0v5
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 onboard-common proftpd-doc python3-dev python3-wheel
  python3.10-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl3
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,902 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 246450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libssl3/changelog.Debian.gz', which 
is different from other instances of package libssl3:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libssl3/changelog.Debian.gz', which 
is different from other instances of package libssl3:amd64` wrong event to use --fix-broken, since nothing is "broken" by apt's definition. The problem is with a non-critical changelog file, not a version conflict. How many other instances of `libssl3` do you have installed?